# How to call same method in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make PDF and Excel report code using same method and want to pass parameters only one time ,but it is showing an error

> NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass) .

Controller Code -

```
def print_application_report
      @from = params[:salary][:from_date]
      @to = params[:salary][:to_date]
      @company = params[:employee][:company_id] 
      @company_location = params[:employee][:company_location_id] 
      @department = params[:employee][:department_id] 
      @employees = Employee.where(company_id: @company.to_i,company_location_id: @company_location.to_i,department_id: @department).pluck(:id)
      @travel_requests = TravelRequest.where(application_date:  @from.to_date..@to.to_date,employee_id: @employees)
      respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.xls {render template: 'travel_requests/application_datewise_report_xls.xls.erb'}
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: 'application_datewise_report_pdf',
              layout: 'pdf.html',
              orientation: 'Landscape',
              template: 'travel_requests/application_datewise_report_pdf.pdf.erb',
              # show_as_html: params[:debug].present?,
              :page_height      => 1000,
              :dpi              => '300',
              :margin           => {:top    => 10, # default 10 (mm)
                            :bottom => 10,
                            :left   => 20,
                            :right  => 20},
              :show_as_html => params[:debug].present?
          end
        end
  end
```

Comment: which line is it highlighting while showing that error?, this error shows that you are pointing to an object to an array which does not exist? check the line no.

Comment: you might have either `params[:salary]` or `params[:employee]` as nil.

Comment: no these are not nil because when I am writing PDF and excel code in different methods it is not showing an error because in PDF code I don't use params[:salary] . Directly I used @from = params [:from_date] . But now i want to use like this so how is it possible to do this .

Comment: what's the line no of error?

Comment: in order to use like that you need to send the params in that way. how are you sending the parameters currently?

Comment: <%= link_to " Excel Report ",print_application_report_travel_requests_path(from_date: params[:salary][:from_date],to_date: params[:salary][:to_date], company_id: params[:employee][:company_id], company_location_id: params[:employee][:company_location_id],department_id: params[:employee][:department_id], format: "xls"), class: "btn btn-xl btn-success fa fa-print" %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check the condition in your controller with the terniary operator and check for the presence of `params[:salary]` and `params[:employee]`,

**Controller:**

```
def print_application_report
      @from = params[:salary] ? params[:salary][:from_date] : params[:from_date] 
      @to = params[:salary] ? params[:salary][:to_date] : params[:to_date]
      @company = params[:employee] ? params[:employee][:company_id] : params[:company_id] 
      @company_location = params[:employee] ?  params[:employee][:company_location_id] :  params[:company_location_id] 
      @department = params[:employee] ?  params[:employee][:department_id] : params[:department_id] 
      @employees = Employee.where(company_id: @company.to_i,company_location_id: @company_location.to_i,department_id: @department).pluck(:id)
      @travel_requests = TravelRequest.where(application_date:  @from.to_date..@to.to_date,employee_id: @employees)
      respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.xls {render template: 'travel_requests/application_datewise_report_xls.xls.erb'}
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: 'application_datewise_report_pdf',
              layout: 'pdf.html',
              orientation: 'Landscape',
              template: 'travel_requests/application_datewise_report_pdf.pdf.erb',
              # show_as_html: params[:debug].present?,
              :page_height      => 1000,
              :dpi              => '300',
              :margin           => {:top    => 10, # default 10 (mm)
                            :bottom => 10,
                            :left   => 20,
                            :right  => 20},
              :show_as_html => params[:debug].present?
          end
        end
  end
```

**Explanation:**

The change I made is,

**`@from = params[:salary]`**

to,

**`@from = params[:salary] ? params[:salary][:from_date] : params[:from_date]`**

the meaning of `params[:salary] ? params[:salary][:from_date] : params[:from_date]` is,

**if there is params[:salary], then take `params[:salary][:from_date]`, if `params[:salary]` is not there, then take `params[:from_date]`**

This line can also be written as,

```
if params[:salary]
    @from = params[:salary][:from_date]
else
    @from = params[:from_date]
end
```

Comment: Thank You so much for helping me . It worked , but please can you explain me how it worked ?

Comment: @AnuJain, added explanation plaese check.

Answer (score 0):

Without the actual line of error, I am making a guess here.
you are sending params as:

```
print_application_report_travel_requests_path(from_date: params[:salary][:from_date],to_date: params[:salary][:to_date], company_id: params[:employee][:company_id]....
```

Here value of param `from_date` is `params[:salary][:from_date]` but you are sending the param directly, **not enclosed in `salary` key**. so all of your params will be available directly inside `params` hash.

you can try changing like this.

```
@from = params[:from_date]
@to = params[:to_date]
@company = params[:company_id] 
@company_location = params[:company_location_id] 
@department = params[:department_id]
```

Comment: If you can post params hash from your server log, when this method executes or line of error then that may help .

Comment: In my development.log file nothing is coming .

Comment: Do you want to see my html form .

Comment: no, just write `p params` after the line `def print_application_report` and check what it prints when you click the link . Check the server console i.e the terminal window in which you started rails server by running `rails server`

Comment: app/controllers/travel_requests_controller.rb:285: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ';' or '\n'
  app/controllers/travel_requests_controller.rb:424: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input